# How to know if a GraphicsPath contains a point in C#

Tags: c#, .net, drawing, system.drawing

I'm using **.NET** to draw a diagram, and I want to highlight objects when the user performs a click on them. It is easy when a figure is fully contained in a rectangle:

```
if (figure.Bounds.Contains(p)) // bounds is a rectangle
```

But I don't know how to manage it if the figure is a complex `GraphicsPath`.

I have defined the following `GraphicsPath` for the figure (the green circle).

[image: GraphicsPath]

I want to highlight the figure when the user click on it. **I would like to know if a `Point` is contained in that `GraphicsPath`.**

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know a **DrawingPath** (you mean probably; graphics.DrawPath) but a `GraphicsPath` has the [IsVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044cxs6w.aspx) method to check if a point is in the path.

```
bool isInPath = graphicsObj.IsVisible(point)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what was I thinking when I wrote this :-). I mean a GraphicsPath.

Answer (score 4):

Using both  .IsOutlineVisible and .IsVisible  together cover the whole thing, border and within border, for this rectangle example, but as you know GraphicsPath can works for different shapes.

```
  bool b = gp.IsVisible(point) || gp.IsOutlineVisible(point, pen);
```

For it in code

```
 Rectangle r = new Rectangle(new Point(50, 100), new Size(500, 100));
 bool b;
 // say Point p is set.
 // say Pen pen is set.

 using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
 using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 44)) {
    gp.AddRectangle(r);
    bool b = gp.IsVisible(point) || gp.IsOutlineVisible(point, pen);              
  }
```