# OnClick Event for Rectangle with C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Question may be phrased wrong and I'm sorry for that.

I have a grid filled with with rectangles. These rectangles are created with C# when the application is started.

I know how to create OnClick Event with the help of XAML, however, my problem is that I don't know how to do one that's created via C# after application has started.

Comment: Are you asking how to create events at runtime?

Comment: Yes! That's what I wanted to ask, but I forgot the word!

Comment: `clickable.Click += ClickHandler;`

Comment: I found one way of clicking rectangle created with C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260397/how-can-i-make-the-rectangles-clickable-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Click` event on [`Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in System.Windows. You can use [`MouseLeftButtonDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseleftbuttondown(v=vs.110).aspx) event like:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
//initialize properties
//Add Event like
rectangle.MouseLeftButtonDown += rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown;
```

and the event handler could be:

```
void rectangle_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```